# How to add Icon beside each item in a List preference In Android along with selected indicator

Tags: android, listview, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, listpreference

I am working on a Xposed module and I need to have an icon beside each item in my List Preferences.
I am able to do this :

http://s20.postimg.org/gjveleu5p/Screenshot_2014_01_18_16_47_38.png

But I want exactly like This one :

http://s20.postimg.org/ee13qwqp9/Screenshot_2014_01_29_12_32_38.png

My Java Class File:

```
package ic.lunar.xposed.exthemer.list.preferences;

import ic.lunar.xposed.exthemer.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class Sim_Icon_List_Preference extends ListPreference {

Context context;

public Sim_Icon_List_Preference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.activity_my_list_preference); //inherited from DialogPreference
}
}
```

My Layout Xml File:

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>   android:layout_width="match_parent"
>   android:layout_height="match_parent"
>   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>   tools:context=".MyListPreference" >
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:src="@drawable/tw_sim_icon_home" />
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imageView2"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
>     android:src="@drawable/tw_sim_icon_heart" />
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: U have to use the custom listview

Comment: I used that option and then only got the icons up there. But I want the icons to be at the side of each item name.

Comment: can u post the xml design for the custom

Comment: Added. Please do help asap

Comment: How have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

When you need a ListPreference with (per row) a text and an icon, you can find a solution via this [description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41806449/3143823).