# How to set icon in ListPreference's item in android

Tags: android, image, icons, listpreference

I want to set the icon in `ListPreference` items in android.

What to write in `ListPreference` or where to write to set the list items icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a **custom** layout for your `ListPreference`.

eg:

```
<android.preference.ListPreference
                android:layout="@layout/your_custom_layout"
                 ....
/>
```

And add what you want to your custom layout.

eg:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/preferences_layout_margin">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/yourIconId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" /> <!-- here i've added an ImageView for icon -->

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/preferences_icon_margin" />

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:maxLines="2" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please give me demo program for this

Comment: You can find a tutorial here: http://www.lucazanini.eu/2014/android/display-icon-preferences/

Comment: i tried same program but it gives me error like this :

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.virenjaru.myapplication1.IconPickerPreference.updateIcon(IconPickerPreference.java:234)
            at com.example.virenjaru.myapplication1.IconPickerPreference.onBindView(IconPickerPreference.java:161)

Comment: @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);

        selectedIconFile = preferences.getString(
                resources.getString(R.string.custom_icon_key), defaultIconFile);

        icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconSelected);
        updateIcon();

        summary = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);
        summary.setText(getEntry(selectedIconFile));

    }

Comment: private void updateIcon() {
        int identifier = resources.getIdentifier(selectedIconFile, "drawable",
                context.getPackageName());

        icon.setImageResource(identifier);
        icon.setTag(selectedIconFile);
    }

Comment: i dont know why icon object is set to null

Comment: Check if the icon id matches with the id in findViewById() method.

Answer (score 3):

When you need multiple uses of a list preference with texts/icons, then you can use this solution.

This version is heavily based on the [nice version of LucaZanini](http://www.lucazanini.eu/en/2014/android/display-icon-preferences/). I made some minor changes to the version so it is only dependant on the own preference attributes. In this way you can use them multiple times. Please refer to his tutorial.

@Luca - thank you very much!

The minor changes are only:

- IconPickerPreference.java, see below.
- You don't need a reference to the strings.xml file. The default value, set at the start is just "0".
- You could improve this version by using an integer for the currentIndex and not a string.

IconPickerPreference:

```
// @Based on the nice version of LucaZanini. Thank you!
public class IconPickerPreference extends ListPreference {
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    private class CustomListPreferenceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<IconItem> {
        private Context context;
        private List<IconItem> icons;
        private int resource;

        public CustomListPreferenceAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<IconItem> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.context = context;
            this.resource = resource;
            this.icons = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.iconName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconName);
                holder.iconImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconImage);
                holder.radioButton = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconRadio);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.iconName.setText(icons.get(position).name);

            int identifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier( icons.get(position).file, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            holder.iconImage.setImageResource(identifier);
            holder.radioButton.setChecked(icons.get(position).isChecked);
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    for (int i = 0; i < icons.size(); i++) {
                        if (i == position) {
                            icons.get(i).isChecked = true;
                        } else {
                            icons.get(i).isChecked = false;
                        }
                    }
                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private class IconItem {
        private String  file;
        private boolean isChecked;
        private String  name;

        public IconItem(CharSequence name, CharSequence file, boolean isChecked) {
            this(name.toString(), file.toString(), isChecked);
        }

        public IconItem(String name, String file, boolean isChecked) {
            this.name = name;
            this.file = file;
            this.isChecked = isChecked;
        }

    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView     iconImage;
        protected TextView      iconName;
        protected RadioButton   radioButton;
    }

    private Context context;
    private ImageView icon;

    private CharSequence[] iconFile;
    private CharSequence[] iconName;
    private List<IconItem> icons;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private Resources resources;
    private String selectedIconFile, defaultIconFile;
    private TextView summary;

    public IconPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        resources = context.getResources();
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes( attrs, R.styleable.attrs_icon, 0, 0);
        try {
            defaultIconFile = a.getString(R.styleable.attrs_icon_iconFile);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);

        CharSequence[] entries = getEntries();
        CharSequence[] values = getEntryValues();
        selectedIconFile = values[ currentIndex].toString();
        icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconSelected);
        updateIcon();
        summary = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.preference_summary);
        summary.setText( entries[ currentIndex]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
        if (icons != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < iconName.length; i++) {
                IconItem item = icons.get(i);
                if (item.isChecked) {
                    persistString( "" + i);
                    currentIndex = i;
                    selectedIconFile = item.file;
                    updateIcon();
                    summary.setText(item.name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue, Object defaultValue) {
        String number = "0";
        if (restorePersistedValue) {
            // Restore existing state
            number = this.getPersistedString( "0");
        } else {
            persistString( number);
        }
        try {
            currentIndex = Integer.parseInt(number);
        } catch( Exception e) {
            ; // skip any error, it will be corrected to 0
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {   
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        builder.setPositiveButton(null, null);
        iconName = getEntries();
        iconFile = getEntryValues();

        if (iconName == null || iconFile == null || iconName.length != iconFile.length) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "IconPickerPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array which are both the same length");
        }

        icons = new ArrayList<IconItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < iconName.length; i++) {
            IconItem item = new IconItem(iconName[i], iconFile[i], ( i == currentIndex));
            icons.add(item);
        }
        CustomListPreferenceAdapter customListPreferenceAdapter = new CustomListPreferenceAdapter(
                context, R.layout.preference_list_icon_picker, icons);
        builder.setAdapter(customListPreferenceAdapter, null);
    }
    private void updateIcon() {
        int identifier = resources.getIdentifier( selectedIconFile, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        icon.setImageResource(identifier);
        icon.setTag(selectedIconFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I transfer icons set to it?

Comment: 1) Cannot resolve symbol preference_list_icon_picker
2) Cannot resolve methos setAdapter
3) No imports included in sample code, which makes it difficult to know which version of Builder class is used.

Another big problem is that Luca Zaninis original project contains lots of deprecated classes. So it is very risky to use a solution like this in production.
It will probably cause lots of crashes.

Please help me find a modern way to add icons to ListPreference! This would make apps so much more user friendly and more fun to use.